# Place to handle exceptions in my classes hierarchy

Tags: python, architecture

I got this-like hierarchy and similar code:

```
class FrontendException:
    pass    
class BackendException:
    pass
class BackendRequest:
    def exec():
        raise BackendException()

class Frontend:
    def cmd_a():
        BackendRequest().exec()

    def cmd_b():
        BackendRequest().exec()
```

**The goal** is to make developer able to operate with `Frontend` objects and exceptions within functions `cmd_x` of `Frontend`.

Basicly, i need a place to handle common `BackendException` types, to raise `FrontendException`. For example:

```
class Frontend:
    def cmd_a():
        try:
            BackendRequest().exec()
        except BackendException as e:
            raise FrontendException()
```

And this will be repeated in each `cmd_x` function! It's so ugly! And it operates with `Backend` things! I want to remove repeated exception handling.
**Any suggestions?**

Btw, my solution, but i find it ugly too, so view it after you'll try to suggest me something. Maybe you'll suggest me something about my solution.

```
class BaseFrontend:
    def exec_request(req):
        try:
            return req.exec()
        except BackendException as e:
            raise FrontendException
class Frontend(BaseFrontend):
    def cmd_a():
        result self.exec_request(BackendRequest())
    def cmd_b():
        result self.exec_request(BackendRequest())
```

**EDIT**: Ok, yes, i know, i dont need to create a lot of classes to build simple API. But, let's see what i need in the result:

```
class APIManager:
    def cmd_a(): ...
    def cmd_b(): ...
```

This manager needs to access HTTP REST service to perform each command. So, if i'll get an error during REST request, i'll need to raise exception APIManagerException - i **can't** leave `raw pycurl exception`, beacause APIManager user don't knows what `pycurl` is, he will be confused with getting `pycurl error` if he will give wrong `ID` as argument of `cmd_x`.
So i need to raise informative exceptions for some common cases. Let it be just one exception - `APIManagerException`. But i dont want to repeat `try...except` block each time, in each command, to each pycurl request. In fact, i want to process some errors in `commands(functions cmd_x)`, not to parse pycurl errors.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0#t=9m26s (Stop Writing Classes, Jack Diederich): In short: try to use the built-in exceptions and create extra ones with care; taxonomies often just add extra burden without benefits.

Comment: Why do you need to convert BackendExceptions into FrontendExceptions?  This looks like Java...

Comment: Yea, KISS, DRY - i know, but i'm building Backend exacly for bloated API, to make people able to use light, sexy functions. Bad thing is - i still need to create a bunch of functions with using of backend requests and i need to handle errors from backend.

Comment: Simply because Backend is a simplistic pycurl wrapper with shortcuts and it raises HTTP404 and related exceptions. But API assumes that 404 error means "resource archieved" and HTTP406 means "error in syntax", but HTTP406 can return different status messages in header, to give information what exacly was a problem. So, in the Frontend class, i want to operate with API-level exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a decorator that wraps all Frontend calls, catches `BackendExceptions`, and raises `FrontendException` if they are thrown. (Honestly, though, it's not clear why `Frontend` and `Backend` are classes and not a set of functions.) See below:

```
class FrontendException:
    pass    
class BackendException:
    pass
class BackendRequest:
    def exec():
        raise BackendException()

class Frontend:

    def back_raiser(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except BackendException:
                raise FrontendException
        return wrapped

    @back_raiser
    def cmd_a():
        BackendRequest().exec()

    @back_raiser
    def cmd_b():
        BackendRequest().exec()
```

Comment: This could be a good idea, but i want to process some exceptions inside the `cmd_a`. But in this case, i can't.